# where to put & in php?

Tags: php, code-readability

i wonder where i should put the & properly.

```
$b =& $a;
or
$b = &$a;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both *reference* the same thing, just a matter of coding style.

Personally, I prefer the `$b = &$a` style for readability, the space from the `&` and `$` throws me off.

Comment: I personally prefer the first way. `$b =& $a;`

Comment: =& might confuse the reader into thinking you meant &=, IMHO.

Comment: @Aistina very true. Good enough reason to change my preference.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually up to you.

I would, like most others, put the `&` directly before the `$` sign of the variable - it makes the code easier to read in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Put it where the code convention you use tells you to put it.

The [PHP manual on references](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) uses `=&` exclusively, whereas the [PHP manual on variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) states

> To assign by reference, simply prepend an ampersand (&) to the beginning of the variable which is being assigned (the source variable).